# EnumerateChildNodesWithName, Can't seem to Remove nodes

Tags: swift, position, nodes, enumerate

I'm trying to remove some nodes from a parent node once they reach a certain x position. The problem I have is that the parent node is changing x position, but the children are not changing x position inside the parent (but are obviously moving with the parent), so when I put in if node.position.x < 300 . . . (remove node), nothing happens. I tried the below code, but this only work one time and then doesn't remove nodes again, which I'm not 100% sure why it stops working.

```
func cleanUp() {
    let positionX = nodeBase.position.x
    nodeBase.enumerateChildNodesWithName("segment", usingBlock: {
        node, stop in
        if node.position.x - positionX < 300 {
            node.removeFromParent()
        }
    })
}
```

Can anybody see where I am going wrong with my code, or can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the condition for a node being removed? Once it moves offscreen?

Comment: Yeah, once it moves offscreen I want it removed, but I was putting it at < 300 to see if it was being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
nodeBase.enumerateChildNodesWithName("segment") { node, _ in
    if !self.intersectsNode(node) {
        node.removeFromParent()
    }
 }
```

`intersectsNode` returns `true` whilst the `node` is inside the bounds of `SKScene`. Therefore, when `intersectsNode` returns `false` you know the node is offscreen and you can remove the node.